# Loading A UIWebView In A TableView Cell

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch, uiwebview

In my tableview as you scroll through the cells they each load a video screenshot/link from Youtube/Vimeo...

But when I first started scrolling through the table view I noticed that each webview continually reloaded itself (what do I mean?) First I would scroll all the way to the bottom of my table view letting each table cell load the web view, therefore when I scroll back up to the top I figured that the webviews would not need to reload again but they did...

In an effort to fix this problem I did something below, but I ran into another problem. When you first open up this scene the table view loads all the visible cell's webviews normally, but when you start to scroll down into the other table view cells I noticed that all it did was take the last webview I loaded when I first opened the scene and put it in to all of the other webviews that I ran into when I scrolled down.

My Code:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] init];
    cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

    NSMutableString *VideoID;
    VideoID = [NSMutableString stringWithFormat:@"9394596"];

    if(indexPath.row == 19) {
        VideoID = [NSMutableString stringWithFormat:@"9820827"];
        NSLog(@"19");
    }
    NSString *htmlStringToLoad = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://player.vimeo.com/video/%@?title=0&amp;byline=0&amp;portrait=0\%%22%%20width=\%%22%0.0f\%%22%%20height=\%%22%0.0f\%%22%%20frameborder=\%%230\%%22", VideoID];
    // Configure the cell...


    UIWebView *thisWebView = (UIWebView*)[cell viewWithTag:10];
    NSString *contentsOfWebView = [thisWebView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:@"document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0].innerHTML"];

    UILabel *thisLabel = (UILabel*)[cell viewWithTag:20];

    if([contentsOfWebView length] < 3) {
        [thisWebView loadRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:htmlStringToLoad]]];
        NSLog(@"IF");
    } else {
        NSLog(@"ELSE");
    }

    thisLabel.text = @"Video Title";
    cell.detailTextLabel.text = @"TEST";

    return cell;
}
```

How can I load every webview in the table view and if I run into webviews that have already loaded, don't load them?

EDIT: Row 19 should load a differnet video, but it doesn't

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because you are reusing the table view cells the web view contained within already has content loaded (it will reuse any available cell that has now been scrolled off screen) thus in your statement:

```
if([contentsOfWebView length] < 3)
```

The contents of the webview ARE greater than 3 so it doesn't do the reload, and thus displays the existing content.

Comment: gamozzii how can I not reuse cells?

Comment: Save them to an NSMutableArray, and if that index on the array is empty, load a new one. but this will kill memory usage. To save on memory, you could cache the webview contents to another array, or a file, and load it from there, but reuse cells.